# $H \subseteq G$. About the embedding(s?) of $\operatorname{Sym}(H)$ into $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ be a *set* and $H \subseteq G$. Given a bijection $u$ on $G \setminus H$, any bijection $\alpha$ on $H$ can be extended to a bijection $\varphi_u(\alpha)$ on $G$ by:

\begin{alignat}{1}
&\varphi_u(\alpha)_{|H}:=\alpha \\
&\varphi_u(\alpha)_{|G \setminus H}:=u \\
\end{alignat}

I note that $\varphi_u(\alpha)=\varphi_u(\beta) \Rightarrow \varphi_u(\alpha)_{|H}=\varphi_u(\beta)_{|H} \Rightarrow \alpha=\beta$, so that $\varphi_u$ is injective for all $u \in \operatorname{Sym}(G \setminus H)$. Differently,

$$\varphi_u(\alpha\beta)=\varphi_u(\alpha)\varphi_u(\beta) \Leftrightarrow u=\iota_{G \setminus H} \tag 1$$

If so, we'd have that among all $\varphi_u$'s, just $\varphi_{\iota_{G \setminus H}}$ is an embedding of $\operatorname{Sym}(H)$ into $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$. I use the conditional, because I'm not sure about $(1)$: is it correct? If so, how can I find (all the) other embeddings of $\operatorname{Sym}(H)$ into $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$?

---

**Edit**

*Remark 1* - Embeddings of $\operatorname{Sym}(H)$ into $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$ are equivalent to faithful actions of $\operatorname{Sym}(H)$ on $G$.

*Remark 2* - If we define:

$$\operatorname{Sym}_G(H):=\{f \in \operatorname{Sym}(G) \mid f_{|H} \in \operatorname{Sym}(H)\}$$

we have that:

- $\operatorname{Sym}_G(H) \le \operatorname{Sym}(G)$;
- the map $\psi \colon \operatorname{Sym}_G(H) \rightarrow \operatorname{Sym}(H)$, $f \mapsto \psi_f:=f_{|H}$ is epimorphism; then, for the First Homomorphism Theorem, we get:

$$\operatorname{Sym}(H) \cong \operatorname{Sym}_G(H)/\operatorname{ker}(\psi)$$

where $\operatorname{ker}(\psi)=\{f \in \operatorname{Sym}_G(H) \mid f_{|H}=\iota_{\operatorname{Sym}(H)}\}$.

Comment: As you wrote, you have an injective function for any $u$, however only $u=\iota$ makes it a *homomorphism*.

Comment: It is confusing in a question about groups to use $G$ and $H$ to denote sets rather than groups. But in general, for integers $m < n$, it would be very difficult to describe all embeddings of $S_m$ into $S_n$.

Comment: @Derek Holt, You are right, but I preferred to run the risk because by using, e.g., $X$ and $Y$ instead, I couldn't keep in mind "which one was inside the other" (with $G$ and $H$ this is easier "by tradition"). Partly amended with the italics in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In other words, given $x \in G\setminus H$, if we have $u(x) = \varphi_u(\alpha\beta)(x) = \varphi_u(\alpha)\circ \varphi_u(\beta)(x) = u(u(x))$, we can conclude $u(x) = x$ for all $x \in G\setminus H$. You should argue why this is true.

As far as finding other embeddings of Sym($H$) in Sym($G$), what you have shown is that in this construction the embedding depends solely on the embedding of $H$ into $G$. Can you use this to find all of them arising this way?

Edit: as Derek Holt points out in the comments, *not all* embeddings Sym($H$) into Sym(*G*) arise in this way. For instance, if $|G| = 2|H|$, then you can have Sym($H$) act on two disjoint subsets of $G$ at once.

Comment: But there are lots of embeddings of ${\rm Sym}(H)$ into ${\rm Sym}(G)$ that are not induced from embeddings of $H$ into $G$.

Comment: Yes you are right, that's a good point.

Comment: @Rylee Lyman, when you say "in this construction the embedding depends solely on the embedding of $H$ into $G$. Can you use this to find all of them arising this way", does it mean that based on $H \subseteq G$ solely we can build other embeddings further than "mine"? Besides, when you say "not all embeddings etc." shall I mean irrespective of being $H \subseteq G$? Finally, I've edited the post with some more thoughts triggered by your answer and comments, just to see if some of them goes in the right direction.

Comment: Maybe I got the point: I should look at the faithful actions of $\operatorname{Sym}(H)$ on the subsets $K \subseteq G$, in the two cases a) $H \subseteq K$ and b) $H \nsubseteq K$ (if this latter means necessarily $H \cap K=\emptyset$, still I don't know). Am I on the right way?